# How set defaults on wpLink()

Tags: wp-admin, tinymce, editor, quicktag

With WP 3.2, WordPress maybe has a new function to add Link-Quicktags to the editor. But I found an function to set defaults for the link-button:

Take a look at [wplink.js Line 278](http://wpseek.com/source/wp/latest/nav.html?wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wplink/js/wplink.dev.js.source.html).

```
    setDefaultValues : function() {
        // Set URL and description to defaults.
        // Leave the new tab setting as-is.
        inputs.url.val( 'http://' );
        inputs.title.val( '' );

        // Update save prompt.
        inputs.submit.val( wpLinkL10n.save );
    },
```

How is it possible to set the values for a custom value?

Is this possible and can you help me?

Thanks for an answer from an JavaScript Expert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also an small example for change the url in link-button to use the url from installed blog. Use print JS in footer, not an include from js file via `wp_enqueue_script()` - ist faster vor development, specially for this small requirement, but not so on standard and fine, how the example from the other answer.

[image]

[image]

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Change URL in Link Popup
 * Plugin URI:  http://bueltge.de/
 * Description: Adds a domain link button to the post editing screen.
 * Version:     0.0.1
 * Author:      Frank B&uuml;ltge
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 'fb_add_quicktag_button' ) ) {

    function fb_add_quicktag_button() {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // change link on Link popup in TinyMCE and quicktag popup
            ( function( $ ) {

                if ( typeof wpLink == 'undefined' )
                    return;

                wpLink.setDefaultValues = function () { 
                    $('#url-field').val('<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>');
                };
            } )( jQuery );
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'fb_add_quicktag_button', 9999 );
    add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php',     'fb_add_quicktag_button', 9999 );

}
```

Comment: @B&uuml;ltge +1 ;)

Comment: @kaiser: +1 for read my stuff in the deep

Answer (score 2):

Put the following in your `functions.php`; better is a custom plugin.

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post.php',     'wpse22643_overwrite_wplinks' );
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'wpse22643_overwrite_wplinks' );
/**
 * enqueue script
 */
function wpse22643_overwrite_wplinks( $hook ) {

    // register is important, that other plugins will change or deactivate this
    wp_register_script(
        'overwrite-wplinks', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/overwrite-wplinks.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        '',
        TRUE
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'overwrite-wplinks' );
}
```

Check the path to the js file you want to include above. Then place the following code in the above mentioned js file.

```
( function( $ ) {

    if ( typeof wpLink == 'undefined' )
        return;

    wpLink.setDefaultValues = function () { 
        $('#url-field').val('http://example.com');
        $('#link-title-field').val('This works :)');
        $('#wp-link-submit').val( 'Use this link' );
    };
} )( jQuery );
```

You can change the default values now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is an overwrite of the strings, right? I search for an replace form the default values. BUt for now it is an solution and I will only enhance for translation.

Comment: It is the same way the setDefaultValues sets the defaults.

Comment: I have change your solution, only for codex and that other people use an codex conform example.